# Regarding Javascript files and .htaccess redirect

Tags: javascript, php, apache, .htaccess

I have an Apache/PHP website (i.e. https://portal.mysitehere.net); and I am trying to "hide" some config files and scripts from "the bad people".

I have tried redirecting using .htaccess so I want redirect when people try to browse through the `/includes/` sub-directory of my website (where the java scripts and config files are) they are sent back to the main page, but when I do that, all the java scripts don't work on the site. Is there a better way to do this without breaking java script?

Comment: When you load a page with a script attached, the browser makes a separate request for that attached file. That separate request looks exactly the same to the server as if you went straight to that file. There is nothing different in the requests. Any javascript within your document root you need to reference is available for anyone to load and view the source of. You shouldn't have any sensitive config files that are javascript. If you are talking about php scripts, people can't see the source of the php code through the web server. Only what is echo'd out.

Comment: The js files are not really config files, they are just basic scripts like calendarpopup, validation, etc. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You can't stop someone from viewing or loading the javascript files without blocking all access, including you referencing the scripts within your pages. There really is no need to typically. Even here on Stackoverflow. Press F12, go to the network tab and reload then page. You can see every file loaded, go to that url and it opens the script directly. There should never be anything sensitive in these files as they are meant to be available like this. I'm just wondering now why you would need to hide these files and what is it that you are really trying to do or protect.

Comment: I understand. The main reason is a vulnerability report I ran on my website from https://www.qualys.com. Basically, they state that just because the js is visible via browser, it's vulnerable to "clickjacking". I am looking at ways to do this without having to re-write the code on the website.

Comment: [OWASP has a good article on this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet) and a defense cheatsheet. It essentially boils down to a simple configuration you can send out to tell the browser to not allow viewing the page in a frame (or frames only on your site). This would likely be what that vulnerability report is looking for. It really has nothing to do with scripts on your server but someone creating a page on their server that points a frame to your site. They can then use scripts on their server to do the clickjacking.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I have read this article and it seems that given the way my website is built, the only practical way for me is to use the X-FRAME option, but so far that has been disabling the javascript as well.